# Data step with infile and filename statements

Tags: sas

Could anyone please tell what action this data step does?

```
data _null_;
length fname $1024;
infile a filename=fname;
call symput("a", fname);
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a null datastep that assigns a macro variable `a`.

```
data _null_;              /* Returns no data table */
length fname $1024;       /* Expects variables length and fname, 
                             with string length 1024 */
infile a filename=fname;  /* Reads the first file referenced */
call symput("a", fname);  /* Writes the value of fname to a macro variable a,
                             that can be accessed using &a. */
run;
```

This code will write to the log the value that `a` has been set to:

```
%PUT &a.
```

Answer (score 2):

It will store the value of `fname` (i.e. the filepath) of the last file from the file(s) referenced by `infile a` into a macro variabled named `A`, which can be resolved at a later point by using `&A`.

Comment: Actually, it would be the _first_ file referenced, due to the lack of `input` statement.  `filename a "('c:\temp\test.txt','d:\temp\test.txt')";

data _null_;
length fname $1024;
infile a filename=fname;
call symput("a", fname);
run;

%put &a;`